# Object is not removed before it can collide with other objects

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm createing a very basic HTML5 game but I can't seem to get the collision detection to work correctly. When a bullet collides with a enemy the bullet is set alive variable is set to false, this means it is not draw and isn't used for collision detection, but it still seems it is. Here is my collision detection method

```
//Collision detection between bullet and enemy
for (var j = 0; j < enemies.length; j++ ) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ ) 
    {
        if( pointInRect( bullets[i].xPos, bullets[i].yPos, enemies[j].xPos, enemies[j].yPos, 32, 32 ) && ( bullets[i].alive == true ) )
        {
            bullets[i].alive = false;
            enemies[j].xPos = -100;
        }
    }
}
```

But when it does collides with an enemy sometimes, and only sometimes the bullet will just continue. can anyone see the problem? I can give some more code if needed.

Canvas

Comment: How does `pointInRect()` work? Can you point me to a description?

Comment: Updated with my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When a bullet was created. It used a recycle system that someone helped me with on stackoverflow. but we forgot to do the check on the first creation, here is the code

```
    for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( ! bullets[i].alive && ! bulletDone ) 
        {
            bulletDone = true;
            bullets[i] = new Bullet( player.xPos + 14, player.yPos);
            console.log( "Bullet created" );
        }
    }

    if ( ! bulletDone ) 
    {
        bullets[bullets.length] = new Bullet( player.xPos + 14, player.yPos);
        console.log( "Bullet created" );
    }
```

Basically the line

```
if ( ! bullets[i].alive && ! bulletDone )
```

was

```
if ( ! bullets[i].alive)
```

So even if a bullet was not alive, it would still create a new bullet and then spawn two bullets.